# Sharing a Multifunction Printer/Scanner Over Network

Tags: scanner

So I have an ubuntu server running in my household and I managed to share my printer (Canon MP250) to the rest of the Windows machines (using Samba).

However, I can't quite figure out how to share the scanner (yes the MP250 is a multifunction device). I've attempted SANE with the sanetwain (front end for windows) but that doesn't quite seem to work.

Right now I've resorted to VNC'ing into the ubuntu server and using the scanner app there which dumps files to a shared folder. Sigh. This is a pain.

Does anyone perhaps know how to share the scanner?

Comment: The problem with network scanners is they tend to be very proprietary to manufacturers and you need to have their drivers installed on all machines (sometimes even their software, too) and not all manufacturers have network capable scanners - although the printer is networkable... I think the MP250 is WIA compliant so it should work... I've experienced this for a few clients. Try installing the full Canon MP250 software on your computers and the scanner software should be able to find the MFD on the network (much like how the printer is found)...

Comment: I agree with Big Chris. The only way I have been able to get scanners to be shared over networks is by using manufacturer software (if it is capable).